# 'yield' expression implicitly results in an 'any' type because its containing generator lacks a

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-saga

Argument of type 'T | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T'.
'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'T | undefined'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'T'.
'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'undefined'.  TS2345

```
    3 |   import { NetworkError } from './error'

    4 |   export function* apiCall<K, T extends { callback?: IUICallback }, Tn>(fn: (arg1: T,...arg: Tn[]) => Promise<K>, arg?: T, ...args: Tn[]) {
    5 |    try {
  > 6 |      return yield fn(arg, ...args)
      |                     ^
    7 |    } catch (error) {
    8 |      if (arg && arg.callback && arg.callback.fail) {
    9 |        arg.callback.fail(error)
             }
             throw new NetworkError(error.message)
           }
         }
```

```
    1 | import { call, takeEvery, takeLatest } from 'redux-saga/effects'
    2 | import { STORE_ACTION } from './action'
    3 | import * as api from './api'
    4 | import { apiCall } from '@util/saga'
    5 | import { errorWrapper } from '../sagaError'

    6 | export function* handlePutStoreDetail(action:ReduxActions.Action<IStore.IStore>) {
    7 | console.log(action)
 >  8 | const res = yield call(apiCall , api.getStoreList, action.payload)
 >  9 | action.payload.callback.success(res.data)
   10 | }

   11 | export default function* watchStoreActions() {
   12 | yield takeLatest(STORE_ACTION.UPDATE_AGE, errorWrapper(handlePutStoreDetail))
   13 | }
```

Comment: `arg` is `T|undefined`, but `fn` accepts `arg1: T`. Why are you using `function*`/`yield` here? Please edit your question to include some information about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow. Please create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which when dropped in an online editor like [Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?) makes it easy to be debugged.

Answer (score 0):

The types for the function `fn` say that the first argument is required, but the argument `arg` that you are calling it with is optional.

You need to change the type for `arg` such that is is required.  `arg: T` instead of `arg?: T`.

If the `arg` is truly optional, then you need to instead change the types for `fn`.  Here I am using a generic for `args` that allows for an empty array, but requires that if there *is* a first argument then it must be of type `{ callback?: IUICallback }`.

```
export function* apiCall<K, Args extends ([] | [{ callback?: IUICallback }, ...any])>(
  fn: (...args: Args) => Promise<K>,
  ...args: Args
) {
  try {
    return yield fn(...args);
  } catch (error) {
    const arg = args[0];
    if (arg && arg.callback && arg.callback.fail) {
      arg.callback.fail(error);
    }
    throw new NetworkError(error.message);
  }
}
```

FYI you do not *need* to use a generator as the inner function for `yield call`.  You can `yield call` a regular `async` function.